# oracle Transactions

Tags: oracle

is it possible to have only DDL statements with a transaction? and if so, is it possible to get it rollback to the original state, if any one of the DDL statement fails?

Thanks & Regards,
priya.R

Answer (score 6):

in Oracle [a DDL statement implicitely commits before and after](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_1001.htm#i2099120) the statement. Each statement is an independant transaction and you won't be able to rollback a successful statement.

A DDL statement however is always atomic: it either succeeds entirely or fails entirely.

Comment: @Vinegar: I'm not sure why Oracle commits before a DDL. Probably to release DML Locks and acquire DDL locks on the objects.

Comment: Yeah, may be. It makes sense.